# Using sed to consolidate diff output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have this output as a result of comparing files with `diff`:

```
< IF-Name :STRING: "lns-wall-01-t2"       Index:Gge32: 260
---
> IF-Name :STRING: "lns-wall-01-t2"       Index:Gge32: 25
```

I need this output:

```
lns-wall-01-t2 old:260 new:25
```

I want to use sed.

Answer (score 5):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
/^</ { old = $NF }
/^>/ { str = $4 ; gsub(/"/,"",str) ; printf "%s old:%s new:%s\n", str, old, $NF }
' your_files_list_here
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response .I am trying to put this in script it gives error : Rep_Scripts='/home/scripts'
for i in `cat $Rep_Scripts/diff.txt | awk '
/^</ { old = $NF }
/^>/ { str = $4 ; gsub(/"/,"",str) ; printf "%s old:%s new:%s\n", str, old, $NF }
'
done

Comment: In your command line there are missing a few `;` between the commands (assuming it's a on-liner as presented here), and a loop over a single file is unnecessary anyway. Moreover, `awk` can accept a list of files as arguments. - Instead of using a loop try this call: `awk ' ... ' "$Rep_Scripts"/diff.txt`, where the file argument is directly read by `awk`. In case you will have more than one file to process extend the argument list or use wildcards, as in: `awk ' ... ' "$Rep_Scripts"/*.txt`.

Comment: If you have issues with your code, please post the error message.

Comment: I try it..the script is not able to be executed and and no error on compiling so what could be the problem

Comment: In case it's not clear, I've explicitly appended in my answer where the files list is to be placed. - Beyond that; what do you mean by "the script is not able to be executed"? - You certainly need not "compile" the `awk` command, as you wrote, just call it.

Comment: I use the sed command thankyou for your help

Comment: If you can run the `sed` program you should also be able to run the `awk` program. - It would anyway be interesting what you missed, and what error you see.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '
    /^</{
        # first line formatting
        s/^.*"\(.*\)".*: /\1 old:/
        # append next 2 lines
        N
        N
        # exchange from 2nd line begining till last ":" by "new"
        s/\n---.*: / new:/
        }' "$Rep_Scripts"/diff.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

use a different type of diff output:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines f1 f2
```

which gives you a more userfriendly format:

```
F-Name :STRING: "lns-wall-01-t2"       Index:Gge32: 260   |IF-Name :STRING: "lns-wall-01-t2"       Index:Gge32: 25
```

and

```
diff -y ........ |
perl -nE '/"(.*?)".*?32:\s*(\d+).*32:\s*(\d+)/ 
          and say "$1 old:$2 new:$3"'
```